# How to make the table in word using PHPWord which includes multiple rowspan and colspan?

Tags: php, phpword

I have been learning the PHPWord for my academic project, and I also have the latest PHPWord library which supports "vMerge" for rowspan and "gridSpan" for colspan.

I have been finding difficulty in creating one particular type of table structure as shown in the Image below.

[image]

**The problem is** how to have same rowspan for '1','2' and '6' , in this case it is equal to 2.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**edit-1** I have succeeded with basic rowspan and colspan, but I am finding difficulty with this complex table.

Comment: Don't think you can use this forum to ask academic questions here. Please use the search feature and google up stuff. You will find things for sure. Good Luck

Comment: I have been googling for a lot of time, and I know how to create basic rowspan and colspan, it just that I have been finding difficulty with this complex structure

Comment: Column 1,2,6 has colspan 2.
Column 3 has rowspan of 2. Wouldn't this work ??

Comment: Can you please post whatever you have tried ?

Comment: I appreciate that you spent your precious time to read my question and yeah I also understood that Column 1,2,6 has colspan 2. Column 3 has rowspan of 2. but it isn't as easy as just providing the parameter rowspan=2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an example in the samples that is quite close to what you are doing: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_09_Tables.php

and modifying that a bit to achieve your example:

```
$cellRowSpan = array('vMerge' => 'restart');
$cellRowContinue = array('vMerge' => 'continue');
$cellColSpan = array('gridSpan' => 2);

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addText("1");
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addText("2");
$table->addCell(4000, $cellColSpan)->addText("3");
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addText("6");

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(null, $cellRowContinue);
$table->addCell(null, $cellRowContinue);
$table->addCell(2000)->addText("4");
$table->addCell(2000)->addText("5");
$table->addCell(null, $cellRowContinue);

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2000);
$table->addCell(2000);
$table->addCell(2000);
$table->addCell(2000);
$table->addCell(2000);
```

tested with 0.13.0 version (for some reason libreoffice didn't like the two adjecent cells with vMerge continue definitions and didn't display them as expected, but word did display them nicely as expected)

Comment: I'm useing 0.18.3 have the same problem with Libre, Google Docs but working fine with Word Online. So, I try to change save document to `ODText`...it's broke! I try again with `RTF`...it's broke even more!! 