# Merge cols or rows in PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

Is it possible to merge cols or rows in templateprocessor?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the table in word using PHPWord which includes multiple rowspan and colspan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124184/how-to-make-the-table-in-word-using-phpword-which-includes-multiple-rowspan-and)

Comment: sorry @Sean, i ask this only for document that i have already make (template) and i have value for it but its only use 1 row / cols merged. not like the link you give, it not use template. 
So i think its not duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Use:

```xml
<w:vMerge w:val="continue"/>
```