# Create a table - phpword

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I am trying to create a table with phpword. however I am struggling with the configuration syntax of this table.

Below is my code:

```
    // Define table style arrays
    $styleTable = array('borderSize'=>2, 'cellMargin'=>10);
    $styleFirstRow = array('borderBottomSize'=>5, 'bgColor'=>'#D3D3D3');
    // Define cell style arrays
    $styleCell = array('valign'=>'center', 'bgColor'=>'#D3D3D3');
    $styleCellBTLR = array('valign'=>'center');
    // Define font style for first row
    $fontStyle = array('bold'=>true, 'align'=>'center');


    // Add table style
    $wordTest->addTableStyle('CoverLine', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);
    // Add table
    $table = $newSection->addTable('CoverLine');
    // Add row
   // $table->addRow(200);
    // Add cells
   // $table->addCell(10000, $styleCell)->addText('Employer Details ', $fontStyle);
    //$table->addCell(1800)->addText($curriculum->curriculum_code);

    $table->addRow(500);
    $table->addCell(2200, $styleCell)->addText(' Code', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(5000, $styleCell)->addText(' Title', $fontStyle);

    $table->addRow(500);
    $table->addCell(2200)->addText('', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(5000)->addText('', $fontStyle);
    $table->addRow(500);
    $table->addCell(2200, $styleCell)->addText('', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(1200, $styleCell)->addText(' Name', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(2500, $styleCell)->addText(' Email', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(' Phone', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(' Logo', $fontStyle);
    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(700, $styleCell)->addText(' Development Quality Partner', $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText('');
```

The picture below shows what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

and What I am getting is too different from the goad.
Please assist.  I've going through the phpword documentation and seems like I missing something.

Comment: What's your goal/desired output?

Comment: The picture attached to the question is the desired output @Phil

Comment: so did you check / try the things from my answer?

Comment: You're example code is very minimal, but not complete and/or verifiable. Please see _[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table grid doesn't work with just playing with cell widths to achieve cells that span multiple columns or rows; the cells spanning multiple columns and multiple rows need to be explicitly defined.

You can find another similar question with answer example at [How to make the table in word using PHPWord which includes multiple rowspan and colspan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124184/how-to-make-the-table-in-word-using-phpword-which-includes-multiple-rowspan-and/38197466#38197466)