# table and text in saved document

Tags: php, docx, phpword

i have code

```
$html = "<p>text text text</p><table><tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr></table><p>text text text</p>";

    require_once '/vendor/phpword/vendor/autoload.php';
    $pw = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $pw->addSection();
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($pw, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('name.docx');

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=name.docx');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

in saved document i have not table, only text. table tags remove and insert as text. how fix this? I have the text itself contains a table and I can not add it separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the table in word using PHPWord which includes multiple rowspan and colspan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124184/how-to-make-the-table-in-word-using-phpword-which-includes-multiple-rowspan-and)

Comment: no, these are completely different questions. I have the text itself contains a table and I can not add it separately.

Comment: tested example html https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_26_Html.php

and get

SAXException: [word/document.xml line 2]: unknown error